# In CakePHP 2.x ORM + use Function MySQL AND NameClass Models remove ;(

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm, model

Problem, how to make the ORM CakePHP, do not waste my table name or class, when a flame fied with a mysql function for example SUM() "sum(SenasaPedidosDetalles.kg_reales) total_kg_reales".

Example Code In:

Print: http://s25.postimg.org/7z1fiwpyn/Print_de_pantalla_612.jpg
[image]

Example Data Out:

Print: http://s25.postimg.org/ahn4jlbov/Print_de_pantalla_614.jpg
[image]

What is the best solution to this problem with CakePHP 2.x ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** As noticed by AgRizzo in the comment section, you should create the virtual field when you need it:

```
$this->Model->virtualFields['total_kg_reales'] = 'SUM(Model.kg_reales)';
$this->Model->find(...) ;
```

---

You could use a virtual field (in your model):

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'total_kg_reales' => 'SUM(SenasaPedidosDetalles.kg_reales)'
);
```

And if you want to deal with model aliases (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html):

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['total_kg_reales'] = sprintf(
        'SUM(%s.kg_reales)', $this->alias
    );
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Setting virtual fields in the constructor is usually best so that aliasing can be correctly handled as shown. I've often found assuming the alias by directly assigning the virtual fields property problematic.

Comment: I didn't think you _should_ create a virtual field in the constructor when it is an aggregate SQL function (MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG). My reasoning (since I can't test right now): Unless every SQL query  (i.e., executing a  `find` on this model) has a `GROUP BY`, the `find` will only return 1 row. **tl;dr I think you want to create the virtual field immediately before the `find`**

Comment: @AgRizzo You're probably right (I can't test it either). I updated my post for the moment (I'll check later for the detailed information).